# Is there a word for an obsolete phrase that is still used? Such as "dial the number"?

Tags: single-word-requests

"Tape a TV show" "Film at 11" "Roll down the window" "Dial 911" etc., etc. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean *anachronism*?

Comment: Another example is the floppy disk "Save" icon used in many software applications. Many people today would not know what those are.

Comment: @dangph I remember 5 1/4 inch truly floppy disks... Now your making me feel old!

Comment: @Gary my memories of 8" disks scoffs at your memories of 5 1/4" disks!

Comment: I wonder if there is a technical term in linguistics for this kind of thing because a  word can become accepted in the new sense with no whiff of anachronism.  For example "They sailed to Alaska last summer on a cruise ship." would not be considered anachronistic.

Answer (score 1):

***[Anachronism](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/anachronism)***

> A thing belonging or appropriate to a period other than that in which
>   it exists, especially a thing that is conspicuously old-fashioned.

(Oxford)

Here [is an example](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2051332/Downton-Abbey-writers-string-language-gaffes.html) of it in use, from a tabloid newspaper article about a costume drama:

> 'Everything in the garden is rosy': The anachronistic phrase was said
>   by Head Housemaid Anna Smith... to Lord Grantham's valet John Bates...

(Daily Mail)

Comment: I believe phrase the garden is rosy is anachronistic because it's no longer commonly used.  If instead, a word is still the most common way of saying something and it evolved from it's original reference I don't think it is either anachronistic or an anachronism.  However, it depends on what the OP is looking for as a few of his examples are beginning to lose favor. If a word is still appropriate to use and not conspicuously old fashioned perhaps it just has an interesting etymology?

Comment: Reading that piece you referenced , they use the term anachronistic as I know it and as I read the definition.  The key is that a play set in an earlier period used a phrase incorrectly,  not because it was "dated" but because the phrase had not been coined yet in the period the play was set: "Characters in the second series – written by Julian Fellowes and set in the First World War – have been uttering phrases not popularised until 40 years later.

Answer (score 0):

Anachronism?

Arguably, those phrases aren't obsolete. Maybe the original meaning of them and the implied technology behind them may be obsolete, but they are still used in the contemporary vernacular. They are valid phrases; their meanings have evolved.